# Project: sahat/hackathon-starter: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, node-inspector

my problem is, that I can't debug (node-inspector) my project anymore, because some files for express couldn't be found. The problem comes only up, when I use the debugger.
Because of this problem, I installed the project approximately 10 times from the scratch. :(

Does anybody of you has an idea, what the reason is?

My system: Windows 7, 
Project: "sahat/hackathon-starter"
Express: "version": "4.8.3",
node-inspector 0.7.4

```
    fs.js
fs.statSync = function(path) {
nullCheck(path);
return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
};
```

debugger says: "Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory"
path: "c:\bpr\node_modules\express\lib\node_modules\utils-merge

real path:
path: "c:\bpr\node_modules\express\node_modules\utils-merge

I would think the required path must be wrong, but can't believe it.

```
Express:index.js
module.exports = require('./lib/express');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having this problem too (using just plain old express).

Comment: Because I think that is a problem coming up from node-inspector I opened there a issue. https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/412

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find the answer.
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/412

Turn the icon "pause on all exceptions" on the buttom of your console off.